# How do I prove ∀x(H(x) → ∀y(H(y) → ¬A(x,y))) ⊢ ¬∃x∃y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) ∧ A(x,y))?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I have a proof that I'm stuck on with multiple quantifers. Here's the question: ∀x(H(x) → ∀y(H(y) → ¬A(x,y))) ⊢ ¬∃x∃y((H(x) ∧ H(y)) ∧ A(x,y)). I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: As per comment received yesterday, you have to use Existential Elimination twice.

Comment: Steps 3 and 4 are the assumptions for two nested $(\exists \text E)$. After 13 you have 14. $\bot$ that closes the inner one and after that you have 15. $\bot$ that closes the outer one. Now you can conclude with step 16. that uses $(\lnot \text I)$.